# Disable Ubuntu One FaceBook Sync

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, facebook

I have a question about the Facebook sync. I activate this function as I had no contacts stored in Ubuntu One. Now I uploaded all my contacts to ubuntu one but I don't see any FB contacts, link or merge. So I think I must reset the sync or?
But when I select "Disable Facebook sync (linked to: https://one.ubuntu.com/contacts/sync)" nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for raising this issue, it seems to be a bug on our end. I have reported it so you can follow its progress: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/923726

Comment: Hi, sorry but your link don't work..